# How do I include pre-installed images in a theme?

Tags: theme-development, images

If I made a theme or converted an HTML one into Wordpress, how do I include images so that they sort of come pre-installed with the theme?

Is there a way to do it by pre-programming it or the only way is to supply a demo contents?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean by preinstalled images? Examples would be super useful

Comment: As far as I know images are stored in a database. So when you want to add an image to your page or post you upload it to the media library and then include it. Can I make such a theme where you install it and it already has some pages e.g. about us with images? Without requiring the user to upload those images?

Comment: Images aren't stored in the database, there are posts of type `attachment` yes, but the actual file is in the uploads folder, any solution would need to create an attachment, probably using `media_handle_sideload` along with a check to see if it's already been done, and you'll want to ask how to run code when a theme is first activated. However I recommend against auto-creating pages on theme activation ( especially since the user may just be previewing the theme, and have their menus set to auto-add top level pages, hey presto you just broke their site )

Comment: @TomJNowell, ah good point. Thanks very much! You should answer this question so that I can choose it as the best one

Answer (score 0):

As per comments of @TomJNowell you can include images as files with your theme, but you shouldn't automatically insert them as attachments in the database and neither should you generate pages on theme activation. The user might be just checking out your theme and end up with stuff in his database het doesn't want.

What you could do is include an option with your theme, allowing the user to choose whether he wants images and pages preinstallend on his theme. There are three functions you will need for this:

1. [`media_handle_sideload`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload) to transfer the image from your theme's directory to the uploads directory and make entries in the database
2. [`wp_insert_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) to generate a page/post
3. [`set_post_thumbnail`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail) to make sure the image you have handled under 1 is attached to the post you generated under 2. You will need some clever logic to keep track of ID's in order to get to this step.

Depending on what your images are supposed to do, you may skip steps 1 and 3 and simply insert the images in the post content, loading them from the theme's directory.